# android: install app without user intervention

Tags: android, installation

I want to install an application on Android without user intervention. I am using the permission `INSTALL_PACKAGES` and I am installing the app in the "/download/" folder. Once the download is finished, a dialog box appears asking me to install the app. How to hide this dialog and install the application without user intervention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, **You can't**. Android framework doesn't allowed you to do that. Android has a some restriction for **Security Purpose**, don't try to break it.

Answer (score 0):

INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is only allowed to system apps, installed in /system/app.

For other applications, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hidden API android.content.pm.IPackageInstallObserver by reflection :

```
public class PackageManagement {
public static final int INSTALL_REPLACE_EXISTING = 0x00000002;
public static final int INSTALL_SUCCEEDED = 1;

private static Method installPackageMethod;
private static Method deletePackageMethod;


static {
    try {
        installPackageMethod = PackageManager.class.getMethod("installPackage", Uri.class, IPackageInstallObserver.class, Integer.TYPE, String.class);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void installPackage(PackageManager pm, Uri mPackageUri, IPackageInstallObserver observer, int installFlags, String installerPackageName) {
    try {
        installPackageMethod.invoke(pm, mPackageUri, observer, installFlags, installerPackageName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Import android.content.pm.IPackageInstallObserver into your Project.
Your app must be system.
You must activate the permission android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES in your manifest